# Correct Definition of the continuous limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $D \subset \mathbb R$, $y \in \overline D$ and $f:D \to \mathbb R$. I always thought the definition of the limit $a = \lim\limits_{x \to y}f(x)$ was
$$\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists \delta > 0\;\forall x \in D: |x-y|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - a| < \epsilon.$$ Turns out the correct definition is
$$\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists \delta > 0\;\forall x \in D: 0<|x-y|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - a| < \epsilon.$$
This excludes $x=y$. Is there any reason to exclude that point, meaning does anything break if we don't do that? Would it be acceptable to use the former definition?

Comment: The limit shouldn't care about what happens exactly at $x=y$, so it is excluded.

Comment: $~x = y~$ is excluded to facilitate distinguishing between the limit existing as $~x \to y,~$ and the function being continuous at $~y.~$

Comment: What is “the continuous limit”?

Answer (score 1):

It will be more informative to see how the two definition are related to each other. To this end, let us denote the "limit" under OP's first definition by $\displaystyle \underset{x\to y}{\operatorname{Lim}} f(x)$:

$$ \underset{x\to y}{\operatorname{Lim}} f(x) = a
\quad\iff\quad
[\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in D, |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x) - a| < \varepsilon ]$$

Then we have the following:

1. If $y \in \overline{D}\setminus D$, then $\underset{x\to y}{\operatorname{Lim}} f(x) = a$ if and only if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = a$.
2. If $y \in D$, then $\underset{x\to y}{\operatorname{Lim}} f(x) = a$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $y$, or equivalently, both $f(y) = a$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to y} f(x) = a$ holds.

So, $\underset{x\to y}{\operatorname{Lim}} f(x)$ *does care* about what happens for $f$ exactly at $y$ (and even requiring continuity at that point), rendering it too restrictive as a candidate of limit notion in many situations.

Comment: I found out both definitions exist and get used by different authors. In some german literature (e.g. H. Amann, J. Escher: Analysis I. Birkhäuser, Basel 1998, ISBN 3-7643-5974-9. p. 255.), the non-punctured version of the definition gets used, which also allows the limit to exist at isolated points and, as already mentioned by some commentors, forces $f$ to be continous in order for the limit to exist for $y \in D$. On the german Wikipedia entry for the limit, there is a small section explaining this new definition (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenzwert_(Funktion)#Neuerer_Grenzwertbegriff).